# markov chain: 2 state chain

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a machine. It has two states, broken or working.  If it is working, then it will be broken with probability $q=0.1$. If the machine is working, I will make \$1000 dollar a day. If it is broken, then repairman will charge charge me \$ $200/(1-p) $ a day to repair. He will fix the machine with probability p. Assume the transition from broken to working (and wise versa) is independent. Find p that maximize the expected profit.

**Attempt:**

2 state markov chain. Let state 0 be working, and let state 1 be broken. The state transition matrix is:

\begin{pmatrix}
  1-q & q \\
    p & 1-p  \\
 \end{pmatrix}

The steady state distribution is calculated by (omit showing my calculation process here since it is well-known)
: $\pi_0=q/(p+q),  \pi_1=p/(p+q)$

**The expected profit is: $1000*\pi_0-200/(1-p)*\pi_1$.  (Do you think this is correct)?**

Comment: You have the right idea, but you made a mistake in computing $\pi_0, \pi_1$ (I believe you swapped the $p$s and $q$s).  The equation should be $$\pi_{working}q= \pi_{broken}p$$.

Comment: To verify, you can get the same answer from _renewal theory_: $$\mbox{time avg profit} = \frac{1000E[working] -\frac{200}{1-p}E[broken]}{E[working] + E[broken]}$$ where $E[working]$ is the average duration of a working interval, and $E[broken]$ is the average duration of a broken interval.

Comment: In that case, $E[working]/(E[working]+E[broken])$ would be the stationary distribution?

Comment: Yes, $\pi_{working} = \frac{E[working]}{E[working]+E[broken]}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed it a bit. It should be: $\pi_0=\frac{p}{(p+q)},  \pi_1=\frac{q}{(p+q)}$
So the profit is:
$$-200\frac{0.1}{(1-p)(p+0.1)}+1000\frac{p}{p+0.1}$$
So you have to find the optimum between 0 and 1. The first derivative is:
$$-20\frac{2p-0.9}{(1-p)^2(p+0.1)^2}+1000\frac{0.1}{(p+0.1)^2}$$
You put it equal to zero and you get the sollution, which is: $p=\frac{12-\sqrt{26}}{10} \approx 0.690098049$